# Facebook module in Titanium

Tags: facebook, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I want to use the Facebook module in Titanium.

In the new version 4.x.x I have to put de `appID` into the `tiapp.xml` but I need to change this parameter programatically.

I know that in the documentation appear this:

> appid property -- The Facebook application ID can no longer be set
>   programmatically in the application. Set the Facebook application ID
>   in the tiapp.xml file. For more details, see 'Getting Started' below
>   for more details.

But I need to know if somebody has a trick to do this or if is possible to use a 3.x.x version of the Facebook module.

Or if you know another alternative.....

Thank you, this is very important for me.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't change that programmatically, sorry.

Comment: There aren't an alternative? In my app depend on the user choice the facebook app id is diferent because they register in a different site

Comment: I'm afraid not, but you could go through http://gitt.io/search?q=facebook and see if there's one that lets you set it at run-time.